# Where to save user informstion when user logs in with facebook in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-facebook-login

I am using a Facebook login in my Flutter app. Where do I store the user information who logged in using Facebook as the user did not register himself on the application?

Answer (score 0):

[This package should help you](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage)

You can do this manually but having a package is great.